# On python installation, does the setup write any private information on any of the files from the installation folder?

Tags: privacy, python

I'm trying to develop some tools to share with people made with a custom python installation.

I've copied the python installation folder into a .zip with the purpose to share with friends and others alike

And I've made a `.cmd` script that unzips the files on their computer.

Does the Python setup write any private information to any file on the install folder?

Comment: What kind of information do you consider private? Would you consider timezone private?

Comment: timezone, no! Any information from the user(file system structure, pointers to specific files) that can identify him, somehow!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. If you're just packing it into a zip file, then are you asking if the zip file contains any sensitive information? Or by installation folder do you mean the system folder that contains your Python binaries and libraries?

Comment: The latter, yes! I've created a zip file that contains a clean python installation (x64) inside. And shared with anyone who wants...

Comment: I'm not writing this as an answer because I'm not entirely sure (I'm not a Windows person), but I'd be very surprised if the system files (assuming they're pre-compiled) contained anything sensitive whatsoever.

Comment: Fair enough!! I also doubt it... cause my program does exactly it's job without any problem, but I hope people understand my concern... maybe I'm being too paranoid!!!

Comment: Maybe can leak something from the user that gets and writes to some needy readable file on installation runtime! Or is just an extraction process?!

Comment: Why do you need to include the Python libraries anyway? Why not just your Python script?

Comment: The program needs the python runtime and the standard library with a few other modules to work, but without some stuff like - dev tools, documentation, tcltk... i run a simple custom installation command and python_setup extract the files to the specified installation folder with exactly my program needs, including the necessary dlls that my program depends. But writes to the registry as a new system/user installation! My extraction copies the files but doesn't write to programs registry... much like a portable app

Comment: Since windows doesn't come with python built-in (yet) unfortunately!!!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question wrt. PII being written to files on the *Python* instal. However, have you considered the use of *[Nuitka](https://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html)*? It is a tool that compiles all dependencies into a stand-alone executable for the target environment.

Comment: Yes, I know Nuitka, pyinstaller and others alike, but for that I need to digitally sign the executables... for free and open source it is not worth spend money... I'm actually finding some alternatives with the "Windows embeddable package"... the files are pre compiled, so I don't need to worry about that anymore...